# Test appwidget using robotium

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-appwidget, robotium

Is it possible to exit application, long press on home screen, select an appwidget, install it and then click on it using robotium?

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the source code to a home screen that supports app widgets, you might be able to use Robotium to write a test for the home screen app, writing tests that can interact with your app widget.